# How to determine if string contains array, object array or function definition

Tags: javascript

I have a solution now, but it's not the best I think.

```
function parseEval(value){
    var result = undefined;
    try {
      result = eval(value);
    } catch (e) { }
    return result;
}
```

So if the `value` is undefined or contains uninterpretable value the function return `undefined`.
If contains an existing function name than returns function object
if contains `"[1,2,3]"` then return int array
if contains `"[{ label: "Choice1", value: "value1" },{ label: "Choice2", value: "value2" }]"` then return an array of objects
I'm open for any solution because the eval has lot of disadvantages. (performance, security, flexibility, maintainability)

Comment: Where do you see anything about jQuery or jQuery UI here ? -1

Comment: Why not use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like everyone else?

Comment: javascript typeof() ..have a look

Comment: "flexibility", "maintainability", where do you see that in this code ? You must be a commercial...

Comment: The jQuery part is that the purpuose of this method is to supply the source option value to jQueryUI autocomplete from html attribute, which must be string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is an internal function that will never be passed any user-supplied data, this might be the best way to go about things.  Otherwise, you would probably be better off using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse data and look up functions and other non-JSON data in a whitelist:

```
var someObject = {
    aFunction: function() {},
    anInt: 42
};

function parse(value) {
    var result;
    try {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    } catch(e) {
        return someObject[value];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One side question. Now my parse accept only global function. My catch part contains return window[value]. what if I have a jui object contain a Button method, so the jui.Button is an Object, (Function). How to check if the value is jui.Button?

Comment: @Péter - you can split the value on `.` and try and find the value for each section:  `valueParts = value.split("."); result = someObject; for (var i=0, l=valueParts.length; i<l; i++) { result = result[valueParts[i]]; if (result == null) { return result; } } return result;`

Answer (score 0):

```
[{ label: "Choice1", value: "value1" },{ label: "Choice2", value: "value2" }]
```

isn't json, but assuming that it should be, because you mentioned that in the question,

```
 console.log(typeof JSON.parse(string))
```

Should work nicely for anything but functions.